# how to handle error 500 when requesting a distant server with guzzle?

Tags: error-handling, guzzle, drupal-8

i am requesting a webservice using :

```
 use GuzzleHttp\Client;
 use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException;
  try {
  $client = new Client();
  $response = $client->request('GET', $url); //it crashes at this line
  $content = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

}
catch (ConnectException $e) {
  \Drupal::logger('amu_hal')->error('incorrect_url'.$url);
}
```

today the distant server return a error 500.

How can i modify my code not to crash my site when it happens?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by distant server you mean a server that takes a long time to connect. You can specify a timeout for the request.

Or perhaps the server returned error 500 and it fails during `json_decode`? You can check the status code returned by the request.

Or even perhaps the code is failing the line that you indicate but the exception `ConnectException` is not being caught? Try using `Exception` as a catch-all to debug this situation.

Instead of using Guzzle directly, I recommend that you use the Drupal wrapper (which uses Guzzle under the hood).

```
$client = Drupal::httpClient();
$request = $client->get($uri, ['connect_timeout' => 5]);
if ($request->getStatusCode() === 200) {
    echo 'Connection Success';
} else {
   echo sprintf('Error %d occurred', $request->getStatusCode());
}
```